# How can I rate limit git-svn?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm looking to git-svn a large repo on a busy and underpowerd svn server. I would like to tell git-svn to be polite and not lag the server for people doing real work. Can I do this?

Comment: Source control isn't a critical part of real work?

Comment: 'real work' is a description people use to differentiate what they are doing from the work others are doing.

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be to run [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to create a clone of the whole Subversion repository first, then run `git svn` against the clone. Alternately, you can use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` (to another machine).

After running `git svn clone` against the Subversion clone, you may have to tweak the Git repository (specifically the Subversion repository URL) to point to your real Subversion server.